# subscription reactivity without user input and a shifting timeframe in the publication

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm a bit new to the meteor world and trying to get the hang of it, but got stuck on something.

I want to display a subset of a calls collection on a page that has no user interaction (see it as an arrival- or departure board at a train station).

I have a publication that containers a subset of calls with a time period.

```
Meteor.publish('currentcalls', function(){
   var start = moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate();
   var end = moment().add(24, 'hours').toDate();
   return Calls.find({appointment: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
});
```

I do a template subscription with an autorun on the template.

```
Template.HomeLayout.onCreated( function() {
   this.autorun(() => {
      this.subscribe('currentcalls');
   });
});
```

When I enter a call into the database within the set time frame of -24 hours and + 24 hours, the call get shown on the template. When I delete one, it gets deleted from the display.

However, when a call is added to the database with a date in the future and not within the timeframe set in the publication, it will not be displayed automatically when time progresses, unless there is a trigger that causes the reactivity on the subscription/publication with user interaction.

What would be a good approach to make sure that the calls that eventually enter or leave the ever shifting timeframe gets displayed or removed from the display?

I tried republish the publication, but it gets an error in the console log on the server:

```
I20160730-11:47:03.521(0)? Ignoring duplicate publish named 'currentcalls'
```

For now I have a quick and dirty reload of the page.

```
Meteor.setInterval( function() {
   window.location.reload();
}, 60000);
```

But I am sure that is not the meteor-way!;-)
Any input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To bring a possible solution to my own question as to what I found on my continuous search and to help someone out that is facing the same in the future:

I found a solution at:

https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish

It works like a charm within my problem setting. I am however still curious if there are other solutions or ways of thinking in using the reactivity within Meteor to solve stuff like I presented.

edit:
Here is some code to complete my answer using that library/package.

```
var start = new ReactiveVar(moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate());
var end = new ReactiveVar(moment().add(24, 'hours').toDate());

Meteor.setInterval( function() {
   start.set(moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate());
   end.set(moment().add(24, 'hours').toDate());
}, 60000);

Meteor.publish('currentcalls', function() {
   this.autorun(function (computation) {
      return Calls.find({appointment: {$gte: start.get(), $lt: end.get()}});
   });
});
```